# google.load breaks a whole website with jQuery already loaded

Tags: jquery, google-api

When I use `google.load` in the script, my whole website just disappear. Here is jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0rc5zL6g/

I'm loading jQuery and then Google's JSAPI. Even with small code like this

```
$(function() {
    google.load('language', '1');
});
```

It hides everything. Just try to uncomment that line in the demo and you will see it working. Also no error in the console.

I use much more scripts and jQuery plugins (they require already loaded jQuery, that's why I don't use `google.load('jquery', '2.2.4');`), but this one will always break the whole website.

I also tried to remove `google.load` from script. Website works like a charm and when I type it in the console, whole website disappear. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google.load()` uses `document.write()` (so that it can load JS immediately so later code doesn't need a callback), so it can only be called synchronously while the document is still rendering.

You can only call that directly in a `<script>` tag, not when the page loads.